# Laravel: Update auth user data then show the view

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

My approach might be wrong or maybe I am entirely wrong.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

- Generate a secret code
- Store that code in the DB
- return the view
- display the updated value.

  ```
  $secret = get_secret();
  $user = auth()->user();
  $user->token = $secret;
  $user->save();

  return view("users.security", compact('user'));
  ```

The problem is when I {{ $user->token  }} it just gives me an entire new value which is different from the value saved in the database. My head is spinning.

[image]

Comment: What's `get_secret()` doing?

Comment: Do you get the same results if you replace `get_secret();` with a constant such as `"test value"` ?  If so, that removes `get_secret()` from the issue.

Comment: @JeffLearman I tried that. what was happening is that the page is being called twice for some reason because I placed a counter and every time I hit that page the value of the counter is incremented by 2 not my +1

Comment: @Daan It returns a string which is a hash code based on a certain loop..

Comment: After going through the network's tab in Chrome Dev I found that my page is loaded twice and the 2nd time it was loaded has referrer parameter which is infact the same page. I am not running any middleware on that function so now I am not sure why is it being redirected to it self after 1 load.

Comment: infact every page is being loaded twice, I have attached the picture.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We don't have the definitions of `view()`, `auth()`, and `get_secret()`.  `get_secret()` should be removed from the MVCE if it can be removed and the issue recurs.

Comment: I have changed the work flow and used ajax call. Thank you for your time tho.